# A 'natural' enumerable metric space with integral distances which is essentially the Euclidean space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry

It is easy to construct a metric space $E_d$ such that all points
of $E_d$ are at mutually integral distance and such that there is a map $\varphi$ from $E_d$ into the $d$-dimensional Euclidean space such that
$\varphi$ preserves distances up to a bounded error and such that $\varphi(E_d)$ is uniformly dense (sufficiently large spheres centered at points of $\varphi(E_d)$ cover the Euclidean space):
Take $\mathbb Z^d$ and define the distance between two
distinct points $a,b\in\mathbb Z^d$ as the integer closest to $\lVert a-b\rVert+3$ (the $+3$ is probably not optimal).

*Is there a more natural metric space with the same properties? Is
there such a space which is optimal in some sense?*

Comment: What you have is already nice, and it is a good start toward more advanced methods and finer results; this belongs to a future chapter on the join theory of metric spaces and diophantine approximations.

Comment: Why do you need to add 3?

Comment: TeX note: `\parallel` spaces poorly for norms; compare $\parallel a - b\parallel + 3$ `\parallel a - b\parallel + 3` to $\lVert a - b\rVert + 3$ `\lVert a - b\rVert + 3`.  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

*(Please, do not "correct" my notation).*

---

Let's go a bit further than in OP's q. -- let the said map (injection) into the Euclidean space be actually a bijection (or simply the identity).

Let $\ E^n\ $ be an n-dimensional space in
$\ \mathbb R^n\ $ with metric $\ \rho.\ $

Every symmetric map $\ \delta: X\times X\to\mathbb R\ $ such that $\ \delta(x\ x)=0\ $ and $\ 1\le \delta(x\ y)\le 2\ $ for arbitrary $\ x\ y\in X,\ $ is a metric; in particular when $\ X:=\mathbb R^n.\ $ Let's define

$$ \forall_{x\ne y;\ x\ y\,\in\,\mathbb R^n}\quad \delta(x\ y)\ :=
    \ 1 + \lceil \rho(x\ y)\rceil - \rho(x\ y) $$
and $\ \delta(x\ x)=0.\ $ Then $\ \delta\ $ is a metric in $\ \mathbb R^n\ $
hence so is $\ d\ :=\ \rho+\delta.\ $ We see that the identity map
$\ \mathbb I_{\mathbb R^n}\ $ satisfies an inequality that improves on the inequality from OP's post:

$$ \rho\,\ \le\,\ d\ <\ \rho+2 $$

Of course, $\ d\ $ assumes integer distances only.

Comment: I know you are quite particular about your notation, but you had exactly one occurrence of $R^n$, which seemed very likely to be a mistake.  I changed it to $\mathbb R^n$ for consistency with the other occurrences (and also ‘OT’ to ‘OP’).  I hope that was all right.

Comment: @LSpice, thank you, that was helpful. #### In general, I mean the arrogance and rudeness of a number of MO participants and of MO's administration when they allow themselves to interfere with my notation free of comas, with the $\ (a;b)\ (a;b]\ [a;x)\ [a;b]\ $ notation for the intervals, etc. And there is **much more** to it. Then, Ironically, they -- in particular MO administration -- show their power and "teach" me politeness -- all this is so ugly. (MO administration has suspended me twice -- as the old saying says: ** give a man power, and he'll make the angels cry**.

Comment: I'm glad your notation is free of comas, but haven't made up my mind about the commas. [But I think I don't like $(x\ x)$].

Comment: @GerryMyerson, sorry for my funny spelling. ###### One may not to **like** something but another thing is to **impose** on others. While MO is just a pathetic tiny nothing on the scale of the human world, the distinction between **not to like vs Impose** is FUNDAMENTAL. In this human world, it is the **imposing** that is the source of the whole **human tragedy**.

Comment: I would say that death is the source of the whole human tragedy, but I fear I'd be going off-topic if I did.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, u'r joking again but this time you could skip it.